# Button icons don't appear as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The buttons appear normally but the icons do not appear. What can I do for them to appear? I've tried several things and none work. I really don't know what else i can do. I tought that the font-awesome link rel was wrong but I think not. Sorry about my english

```css
.azm-social {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 -moz-border-radius: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;
 -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
}
.azm-social:hover, .azm-social:focus, .azm-social:active { outline: 0; opacity: 0.8; color: #fff; }

.azm-btn {
 height: 48px;
 margin: 8px;
 padding: 13px 17px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 21px;
 font-weight: 300;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
}
.azm-btn i { padding-right: 27px; font-size: 21px; line-height: 21px; vertical-align: top; }

.azm-btn i:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -8px;
 left: 70%;
 width: 1px;
 height: 36px;
 background: #ccc;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.azm-size-64 {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding-top: 16px;
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
}

.azm-circle {
 -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%;
}

.azm-long-shadow.azm-facebook {text-shadow:rgb(65,88,147) 1px 1px,rgb(65,88,147) 2px 2px,rgb(65,88,147) 3px 3px,rgb(65,88,147) 4px 4px,rgb(65,88,148) 5px 5px,rgb(65,88,148) 6px 6px,rgb(65,88,148) 7px 7px,rgb(65,89,148) 8px 8px,rgb(65,89,148) 9px 9px,rgb(65,89,149) 10px 10px,rgb(65,89,149) 11px 11px,rgb(66,89,149) 12px 12px,rgb(66,89,149) 13px 13px,rgb(66,89,149) 14px 14px,rgb(66,89,150) 15px 15px,rgb(66,90,150) 16px 16px,rgb(66,90,150) 17px 17px,rgb(66,90,150) 18px 18px,rgb(66,90,150) 19px 19px,rgb(66,90,151) 20px 20px,rgb(66,90,151) 21px 21px,rgb(66,90,151) 22px 22px,rgb(67,90,151) 23px 23px,rgb(67,91,151) 24px 24px,rgb(67,91,152) 25px 25px,rgb(67,91,152) 26px 26px,rgb(67,91,152) 27px 27px,rgb(67,91,152) 28px 28px,rgb(67,91,152) 29px 29px,rgb(67,91,153) 30px 30px,rgb(67,91,153) 31px 31px,rgb(67,92,153) 32px 32px,rgb(67,92,153) 33px 33px,rgb(67,92,153) 34px 34px,rgb(68,92,154) 35px 35px,rgb(68,92,154) 36px 36px,rgb(68,92,154) 37px 37px,rgb(68,92,154) 38px 38px,rgb(68,92,154) 39px 39px,rgb(68,93,155) 40px 40px,rgb(68,93,155) 41px 41px,rgb(68,93,155) 42px 42px,rgb(68,93,155) 43px 43px,rgb(68,93,155) 44px 44px,rgb(68,93,156) 45px 45px,rgb(69,93,156) 46px 46px,rgb(69,93,156) 47px 47px,rgb(69,94,156) 48px 48px,rgb(69,94,156) 49px 49px,rgb(69,94,157) 50px 50px,rgb(69,94,157) 51px 51px,rgb(69,94,157) 52px 52px,rgb(69,94,157) 53px 53px,rgb(69,94,157) 54px 54px,rgb(69,94,158) 55px 55px,rgb(69,95,158) 56px 56px,rgb(69,95,158) 57px 57px,rgb(70,95,158) 58px 58px,rgb(70,95,158) 59px 59px,rgb(70,95,159) 60px 60px,rgb(70,95,159) 61px 61px,rgb(70,95,159) 62px 62px,rgb(70,95,159) 63px 63px,rgb(70,96,159) 64px 64px,rgb(70,96,160) 65px 65px,rgb(70,96,160) 66px 66px,rgb(70,96,160) 67px 67px,rgb(70,96,160) 68px 68px,rgb(71,96,160) 69px 69px,rgb(71,96,161) 70px 70px,rgb(71,96,161) 71px 71px,rgb(71,97,161) 72px 72px,rgb(71,97,161) 73px 73px,rgb(71,97,161) 74px 74px,rgb(71,97,162) 75px 75px,rgb(71,97,162) 76px 76px,rgb(71,97,162) 77px 77px,rgb(71,97,162) 78px 78px,rgb(71,97,162) 79px 79px,rgb(72,98,163) 80px 80px}

.azm-long-shadow.azm-google-plus {text-shadow:rgb(199,68,51) 1px 1px,rgb(199,68,51) 2px 2px,rgb(199,68,51) 3px 3px,rgb(200,68,51) 4px 4px,rgb(200,68,51) 5px 5px,rgb(200,68,51) 6px 6px,rgb(200,68,51) 7px 7px,rgb(201,68,51) 8px 8px,rgb(201,68,51) 9px 9px,rgb(201,68,51) 10px 10px,rgb(202,68,51) 11px 11px,rgb(202,69,51) 12px 12px,rgb(202,69,51) 13px 13px,rgb(202,69,52) 14px 14px,rgb(203,69,52) 15px 15px,rgb(203,69,52) 16px 16px,rgb(203,69,52) 17px 17px,rgb(203,69,52) 18px 18px,rgb(204,69,52) 19px 19px,rgb(204,69,52) 20px 20px,rgb(204,69,52) 21px 21px,rgb(205,69,52) 22px 22px,rgb(205,70,52) 23px 23px,rgb(205,70,52) 24px 24px,rgb(205,70,52) 25px 25px,rgb(206,70,52) 26px 26px,rgb(206,70,53) 27px 27px,rgb(206,70,53) 28px 28px,rgb(206,70,53) 29px 29px,rgb(207,70,53) 30px 30px,rgb(207,70,53) 31px 31px,rgb(207,70,53) 32px 32px,rgb(208,70,53) 33px 33px,rgb(208,70,53) 34px 34px,rgb(208,71,53) 35px 35px,rgb(208,71,53) 36px 36px,rgb(209,71,53) 37px 37px,rgb(209,71,53) 38px 38px,rgb(209,71,53) 39px 39px,rgb(210,71,54) 40px 40px,rgb(210,71,54) 41px 41px,rgb(210,71,54) 42px 42px,rgb(210,71,54) 43px 43px,rgb(211,71,54) 44px 44px,rgb(211,71,54) 45px 45px,rgb(211,72,54) 46px 46px,rgb(211,72,54) 47px 47px,rgb(212,72,54) 48px 48px,rgb(212,72,54) 49px 49px,rgb(212,72,54) 50px 50px,rgb(213,72,54) 51px 51px,rgb(213,72,54) 52px 52px,rgb(213,72,54) 53px 53px,rgb(213,72,55) 54px 54px,rgb(214,72,55) 55px 55px,rgb(214,72,55) 56px 56px,rgb(214,72,55) 57px 57px,rgb(214,73,55) 58px 58px,rgb(215,73,55) 59px 59px,rgb(215,73,55) 60px 60px,rgb(215,73,55) 61px 61px,rgb(216,73,55) 62px 62px,rgb(216,73,55) 63px 63px,rgb(216,73,55) 64px 64px,rgb(216,73,55) 65px 65px,rgb(217,73,55) 66px 66px,rgb(217,73,56) 67px 67px,rgb(217,73,56) 68px 68px,rgb(217,74,56) 69px 69px,rgb(218,74,56) 70px 70px,rgb(218,74,56) 71px 71px,rgb(218,74,56) 72px 72px,rgb(219,74,56) 73px 73px,rgb(219,74,56) 74px 74px,rgb(219,74,56) 75px 75px,rgb(219,74,56) 76px 76px,rgb(220,74,56) 77px 77px,rgb(220,74,56) 78px 78px,rgb(220,74,56) 79px 79px,rgb(221,75,57) 80px 80px}

.azm-long-shadow.azm-twitter {text-shadow:rgb(77,155,214) 1px 1px,rgb(77,155,214) 2px 2px,rgb(77,155,214) 3px 3px,rgb(77,155,215) 4px 4px,rgb(77,156,215) 5px 5px,rgb(77,156,215) 6px 6px,rgb(77,156,216) 7px 7px,rgb(77,156,216) 8px 8px,rgb(77,156,216) 9px 9px,rgb(78,157,217) 10px 10px,rgb(78,157,217) 11px 11px,rgb(78,157,217) 12px 12px,rgb(78,157,217) 13px 13px,rgb(78,157,218) 14px 14px,rgb(78,158,218) 15px 15px,rgb(78,158,218) 16px 16px,rgb(78,158,219) 17px 17px,rgb(78,158,219) 18px 18px,rgb(78,159,219) 19px 19px,rgb(79,159,220) 20px 20px,rgb(79,159,220) 21px 21px,rgb(79,159,220) 22px 22px,rgb(79,159,220) 23px 23px,rgb(79,160,221) 24px 24px,rgb(79,160,221) 25px 25px,rgb(79,160,221) 26px 26px,rgb(79,160,222) 27px 27px,rgb(79,160,222) 28px 28px,rgb(79,161,222) 29px 29px,rgb(80,161,223) 30px 30px,rgb(80,161,223) 31px 31px,rgb(80,161,223) 32px 32px,rgb(80,162,223) 33px 33px,rgb(80,162,224) 34px 34px,rgb(80,162,224) 35px 35px,rgb(80,162,224) 36px 36px,rgb(80,162,225) 37px 37px,rgb(80,163,225) 38px 38px,rgb(80,163,225) 39px 39px,rgb(81,163,226) 40px 40px,rgb(81,163,226) 41px 41px,rgb(81,163,226) 42px 42px,rgb(81,164,226) 43px 43px,rgb(81,164,227) 44px 44px,rgb(81,164,227) 45px 45px,rgb(81,164,227) 46px 46px,rgb(81,164,228) 47px 47px,rgb(81,165,228) 48px 48px,rgb(81,165,228) 49px 49px,rgb(82,165,229) 50px 50px,rgb(82,165,229) 51px 51px,rgb(82,166,229) 52px 52px,rgb(82,166,229) 53px 53px,rgb(82,166,230) 54px 54px,rgb(82,166,230) 55px 55px,rgb(82,166,230) 56px 56px,rgb(82,167,231) 57px 57px,rgb(82,167,231) 58px 58px,rgb(82,167,231) 59px 59px,rgb(83,167,232) 60px 60px,rgb(83,167,232) 61px 61px,rgb(83,168,232) 62px 62px,rgb(83,168,232) 63px 63px,rgb(83,168,233) 64px 64px,rgb(83,168,233) 65px 65px,rgb(83,169,233) 66px 66px,rgb(83,169,234) 67px 67px,rgb(83,169,234) 68px 68px,rgb(83,169,234) 69px 69px,rgb(84,169,235) 70px 70px,rgb(84,170,235) 71px 71px,rgb(84,170,235) 72px 72px,rgb(84,170,235) 73px 73px,rgb(84,170,236) 74px 74px,rgb(84,170,236) 75px 75px,rgb(84,171,236) 76px 76px,rgb(84,171,237) 77px 77px,rgb(84,171,237) 78px 78px,rgb(84,171,237) 79px 79px,rgb(85,172,238) 80px 80px}

.azm-long-shadow.azm-youtube {text-shadow:rgb(187,29,31) 1px 1px,rgb(187,29,31) 2px 2px,rgb(187,29,31) 3px 3px,rgb(188,29,31) 4px 4px,rgb(188,29,31) 5px 5px,rgb(188,29,31) 6px 6px,rgb(188,29,31) 7px 7px,rgb(189,29,31) 8px 8px,rgb(189,29,31) 9px 9px,rgb(189,29,31) 10px 10px,rgb(189,29,31) 11px 11px,rgb(190,29,31) 12px 12px,rgb(190,29,31) 13px 13px,rgb(190,29,31) 14px 14px,rgb(190,29,31) 15px 15px,rgb(191,29,31) 16px 16px,rgb(191,29,31) 17px 17px,rgb(191,29,31) 18px 18px,rgb(191,29,31) 19px 19px,rgb(192,29,31) 20px 20px,rgb(192,29,31) 21px 21px,rgb(192,29,31) 22px 22px,rgb(193,29,31) 23px 23px,rgb(193,29,31) 24px 24px,rgb(193,29,31) 25px 25px,rgb(193,29,31) 26px 26px,rgb(194,30,32) 27px 27px,rgb(194,30,32) 28px 28px,rgb(194,30,32) 29px 29px,rgb(194,30,32) 30px 30px,rgb(195,30,32) 31px 31px,rgb(195,30,32) 32px 32px,rgb(195,30,32) 33px 33px,rgb(195,30,32) 34px 34px,rgb(196,30,32) 35px 35px,rgb(196,30,32) 36px 36px,rgb(196,30,32) 37px 37px,rgb(196,30,32) 38px 38px,rgb(197,30,32) 39px 39px,rgb(197,30,32) 40px 40px,rgb(197,30,32) 41px 41px,rgb(198,30,32) 42px 42px,rgb(198,30,32) 43px 43px,rgb(198,30,32) 44px 44px,rgb(198,30,32) 45px 45px,rgb(199,30,32) 46px 46px,rgb(199,30,32) 47px 47px,rgb(199,30,32) 48px 48px,rgb(199,30,32) 49px 49px,rgb(200,30,32) 50px 50px,rgb(200,30,32) 51px 51px,rgb(200,30,32) 52px 52px,rgb(200,30,32) 53px 53px,rgb(201,31,33) 54px 54px,rgb(201,31,33) 55px 55px,rgb(201,31,33) 56px 56px,rgb(201,31,33) 57px 57px,rgb(202,31,33) 58px 58px,rgb(202,31,33) 59px 59px,rgb(202,31,33) 60px 60px,rgb(203,31,33) 61px 61px,rgb(203,31,33) 62px 62px,rgb(203,31,33) 63px 63px,rgb(203,31,33) 64px 64px,rgb(204,31,33) 65px 65px,rgb(204,31,33) 66px 66px,rgb(204,31,33) 67px 67px,rgb(204,31,33) 68px 68px,rgb(205,31,33) 69px 69px,rgb(205,31,33) 70px 70px,rgb(205,31,33) 71px 71px,rgb(205,31,33) 72px 72px,rgb(206,31,33) 73px 73px,rgb(206,31,33) 74px 74px,rgb(206,31,33) 75px 75px,rgb(206,31,33) 76px 76px,rgb(207,31,33) 77px 77px,rgb(207,31,33) 78px 78px,rgb(207,31,33) 79px 79px,rgb(208,32,34) 80px 80px}


.azm-facebook { background: #4862a3; }

.azm-google-plus { background: #dd4b39; }

.azm-twitter { background: #55acee; }

.azm-youtube { background: #d02022; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
                  
                  <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is it because of .....  from the font awesome website....  Warning!

Apparently, Adblock Plus can remove Font Awesome brand icons with their "Remove Social Media Buttons" setting. We will not use hacks to force them to display. Please report an issue with Adblock Plus if you believe this to be an error. To work around this, you'll need to modify the social icon class names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assure you use a correct link to the CDN, such as:

   ```
   <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
   rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
   ```
2. If your page uses HTTPS, do you link to the font-awesome CSS using HTTPS (replace http:// with https:// in the link above).
3. Reset your browsers cache. (On Chrome do a looong click on the reload button and select Hard Cache Reset)
4. Assure that the `<span>` or `<i>` element you use, uses the FontAwesome font family. For example, it must not just

   ```
   <i class="fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i> but like that <i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
   ```
5. If this doesn't work, there are further [Troubleshooting Ideas](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting) on the Font Awesome Wiki.
6. Check your .htaccess is not blocking ttf, svg, eot, or woff extensions

Answer (score 0):

**Check your link to Font Awesome.**

Here is a complete code that produces this:

[image: Output of document]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
  .azm-social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;
    -o-transition: all .3s; -moz-transition: all .3s; -webkit-transition: all .3s; -ms-transition: all .3s; transition: all .3s;
  }
  .azm-social:hover, .azm-social:focus, .azm-social:active { outline: 0; opacity: 0.8; color: #fff; }

  .azm-btn {
    height: 48px;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 13px 17px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .azm-btn i { padding-right: 27px; font-size: 21px; line-height: 21px; vertical-align: top; }

  .azm-btn i:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 70%;
    width: 1px;
    height: 36px;
    background: #ccc;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }

  .azm-size-64 {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
  }

  .azm-circle {
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .azm-long-shadow.azm-facebook {text-shadow:rgb(65,88,147) 1px 1px,rgb(65,88,147) 2px 2px,rgb(65,88,147) 3px 3px,rgb(65,88,147) 4px 4px,rgb(65,88,148) 5px 5px,rgb(65,88,148) 6px 6px,rgb(65,88,148) 7px 7px,rgb(65,89,148) 8px 8px,rgb(65,89,148) 9px 9px,rgb(65,89,149) 10px 10px,rgb(65,89,149) 11px 11px,rgb(66,89,149) 12px 12px,rgb(66,89,149) 13px 13px,rgb(66,89,149) 14px 14px,rgb(66,89,150) 15px 15px,rgb(66,90,150) 16px 16px,rgb(66,90,150) 17px 17px,rgb(66,90,150) 18px 18px,rgb(66,90,150) 19px 19px,rgb(66,90,151) 20px 20px,rgb(66,90,151) 21px 21px,rgb(66,90,151) 22px 22px,rgb(67,90,151) 23px 23px,rgb(67,91,151) 24px 24px,rgb(67,91,152) 25px 25px,rgb(67,91,152) 26px 26px,rgb(67,91,152) 27px 27px,rgb(67,91,152) 28px 28px,rgb(67,91,152) 29px 29px,rgb(67,91,153) 30px 30px,rgb(67,91,153) 31px 31px,rgb(67,92,153) 32px 32px,rgb(67,92,153) 33px 33px,rgb(67,92,153) 34px 34px,rgb(68,92,154) 35px 35px,rgb(68,92,154) 36px 36px,rgb(68,92,154) 37px 37px,rgb(68,92,154) 38px 38px,rgb(68,92,154) 39px 39px,rgb(68,93,155) 40px 40px,rgb(68,93,155) 41px 41px,rgb(68,93,155) 42px 42px,rgb(68,93,155) 43px 43px,rgb(68,93,155) 44px 44px,rgb(68,93,156) 45px 45px,rgb(69,93,156) 46px 46px,rgb(69,93,156) 47px 47px,rgb(69,94,156) 48px 48px,rgb(69,94,156) 49px 49px,rgb(69,94,157) 50px 50px,rgb(69,94,157) 51px 51px,rgb(69,94,157) 52px 52px,rgb(69,94,157) 53px 53px,rgb(69,94,157) 54px 54px,rgb(69,94,158) 55px 55px,rgb(69,95,158) 56px 56px,rgb(69,95,158) 57px 57px,rgb(70,95,158) 58px 58px,rgb(70,95,158) 59px 59px,rgb(70,95,159) 60px 60px,rgb(70,95,159) 61px 61px,rgb(70,95,159) 62px 62px,rgb(70,95,159) 63px 63px,rgb(70,96,159) 64px 64px,rgb(70,96,160) 65px 65px,rgb(70,96,160) 66px 66px,rgb(70,96,160) 67px 67px,rgb(70,96,160) 68px 68px,rgb(71,96,160) 69px 69px,rgb(71,96,161) 70px 70px,rgb(71,96,161) 71px 71px,rgb(71,97,161) 72px 72px,rgb(71,97,161) 73px 73px,rgb(71,97,161) 74px 74px,rgb(71,97,162) 75px 75px,rgb(71,97,162) 76px 76px,rgb(71,97,162) 77px 77px,rgb(71,97,162) 78px 78px,rgb(71,97,162) 79px 79px,rgb(72,98,163) 80px 80px}

  .azm-long-shadow.azm-google-plus {text-shadow:rgb(199,68,51) 1px 1px,rgb(199,68,51) 2px 2px,rgb(199,68,51) 3px 3px,rgb(200,68,51) 4px 4px,rgb(200,68,51) 5px 5px,rgb(200,68,51) 6px 6px,rgb(200,68,51) 7px 7px,rgb(201,68,51) 8px 8px,rgb(201,68,51) 9px 9px,rgb(201,68,51) 10px 10px,rgb(202,68,51) 11px 11px,rgb(202,69,51) 12px 12px,rgb(202,69,51) 13px 13px,rgb(202,69,52) 14px 14px,rgb(203,69,52) 15px 15px,rgb(203,69,52) 16px 16px,rgb(203,69,52) 17px 17px,rgb(203,69,52) 18px 18px,rgb(204,69,52) 19px 19px,rgb(204,69,52) 20px 20px,rgb(204,69,52) 21px 21px,rgb(205,69,52) 22px 22px,rgb(205,70,52) 23px 23px,rgb(205,70,52) 24px 24px,rgb(205,70,52) 25px 25px,rgb(206,70,52) 26px 26px,rgb(206,70,53) 27px 27px,rgb(206,70,53) 28px 28px,rgb(206,70,53) 29px 29px,rgb(207,70,53) 30px 30px,rgb(207,70,53) 31px 31px,rgb(207,70,53) 32px 32px,rgb(208,70,53) 33px 33px,rgb(208,70,53) 34px 34px,rgb(208,71,53) 35px 35px,rgb(208,71,53) 36px 36px,rgb(209,71,53) 37px 37px,rgb(209,71,53) 38px 38px,rgb(209,71,53) 39px 39px,rgb(210,71,54) 40px 40px,rgb(210,71,54) 41px 41px,rgb(210,71,54) 42px 42px,rgb(210,71,54) 43px 43px,rgb(211,71,54) 44px 44px,rgb(211,71,54) 45px 45px,rgb(211,72,54) 46px 46px,rgb(211,72,54) 47px 47px,rgb(212,72,54) 48px 48px,rgb(212,72,54) 49px 49px,rgb(212,72,54) 50px 50px,rgb(213,72,54) 51px 51px,rgb(213,72,54) 52px 52px,rgb(213,72,54) 53px 53px,rgb(213,72,55) 54px 54px,rgb(214,72,55) 55px 55px,rgb(214,72,55) 56px 56px,rgb(214,72,55) 57px 57px,rgb(214,73,55) 58px 58px,rgb(215,73,55) 59px 59px,rgb(215,73,55) 60px 60px,rgb(215,73,55) 61px 61px,rgb(216,73,55) 62px 62px,rgb(216,73,55) 63px 63px,rgb(216,73,55) 64px 64px,rgb(216,73,55) 65px 65px,rgb(217,73,55) 66px 66px,rgb(217,73,56) 67px 67px,rgb(217,73,56) 68px 68px,rgb(217,74,56) 69px 69px,rgb(218,74,56) 70px 70px,rgb(218,74,56) 71px 71px,rgb(218,74,56) 72px 72px,rgb(219,74,56) 73px 73px,rgb(219,74,56) 74px 74px,rgb(219,74,56) 75px 75px,rgb(219,74,56) 76px 76px,rgb(220,74,56) 77px 77px,rgb(220,74,56) 78px 78px,rgb(220,74,56) 79px 79px,rgb(221,75,57) 80px 80px}

  .azm-long-shadow.azm-twitter {text-shadow:rgb(77,155,214) 1px 1px,rgb(77,155,214) 2px 2px,rgb(77,155,214) 3px 3px,rgb(77,155,215) 4px 4px,rgb(77,156,215) 5px 5px,rgb(77,156,215) 6px 6px,rgb(77,156,216) 7px 7px,rgb(77,156,216) 8px 8px,rgb(77,156,216) 9px 9px,rgb(78,157,217) 10px 10px,rgb(78,157,217) 11px 11px,rgb(78,157,217) 12px 12px,rgb(78,157,217) 13px 13px,rgb(78,157,218) 14px 14px,rgb(78,158,218) 15px 15px,rgb(78,158,218) 16px 16px,rgb(78,158,219) 17px 17px,rgb(78,158,219) 18px 18px,rgb(78,159,219) 19px 19px,rgb(79,159,220) 20px 20px,rgb(79,159,220) 21px 21px,rgb(79,159,220) 22px 22px,rgb(79,159,220) 23px 23px,rgb(79,160,221) 24px 24px,rgb(79,160,221) 25px 25px,rgb(79,160,221) 26px 26px,rgb(79,160,222) 27px 27px,rgb(79,160,222) 28px 28px,rgb(79,161,222) 29px 29px,rgb(80,161,223) 30px 30px,rgb(80,161,223) 31px 31px,rgb(80,161,223) 32px 32px,rgb(80,162,223) 33px 33px,rgb(80,162,224) 34px 34px,rgb(80,162,224) 35px 35px,rgb(80,162,224) 36px 36px,rgb(80,162,225) 37px 37px,rgb(80,163,225) 38px 38px,rgb(80,163,225) 39px 39px,rgb(81,163,226) 40px 40px,rgb(81,163,226) 41px 41px,rgb(81,163,226) 42px 42px,rgb(81,164,226) 43px 43px,rgb(81,164,227) 44px 44px,rgb(81,164,227) 45px 45px,rgb(81,164,227) 46px 46px,rgb(81,164,228) 47px 47px,rgb(81,165,228) 48px 48px,rgb(81,165,228) 49px 49px,rgb(82,165,229) 50px 50px,rgb(82,165,229) 51px 51px,rgb(82,166,229) 52px 52px,rgb(82,166,229) 53px 53px,rgb(82,166,230) 54px 54px,rgb(82,166,230) 55px 55px,rgb(82,166,230) 56px 56px,rgb(82,167,231) 57px 57px,rgb(82,167,231) 58px 58px,rgb(82,167,231) 59px 59px,rgb(83,167,232) 60px 60px,rgb(83,167,232) 61px 61px,rgb(83,168,232) 62px 62px,rgb(83,168,232) 63px 63px,rgb(83,168,233) 64px 64px,rgb(83,168,233) 65px 65px,rgb(83,169,233) 66px 66px,rgb(83,169,234) 67px 67px,rgb(83,169,234) 68px 68px,rgb(83,169,234) 69px 69px,rgb(84,169,235) 70px 70px,rgb(84,170,235) 71px 71px,rgb(84,170,235) 72px 72px,rgb(84,170,235) 73px 73px,rgb(84,170,236) 74px 74px,rgb(84,170,236) 75px 75px,rgb(84,171,236) 76px 76px,rgb(84,171,237) 77px 77px,rgb(84,171,237) 78px 78px,rgb(84,171,237) 79px 79px,rgb(85,172,238) 80px 80px}

  .azm-long-shadow.azm-youtube {text-shadow:rgb(187,29,31) 1px 1px,rgb(187,29,31) 2px 2px,rgb(187,29,31) 3px 3px,rgb(188,29,31) 4px 4px,rgb(188,29,31) 5px 5px,rgb(188,29,31) 6px 6px,rgb(188,29,31) 7px 7px,rgb(189,29,31) 8px 8px,rgb(189,29,31) 9px 9px,rgb(189,29,31) 10px 10px,rgb(189,29,31) 11px 11px,rgb(190,29,31) 12px 12px,rgb(190,29,31) 13px 13px,rgb(190,29,31) 14px 14px,rgb(190,29,31) 15px 15px,rgb(191,29,31) 16px 16px,rgb(191,29,31) 17px 17px,rgb(191,29,31) 18px 18px,rgb(191,29,31) 19px 19px,rgb(192,29,31) 20px 20px,rgb(192,29,31) 21px 21px,rgb(192,29,31) 22px 22px,rgb(193,29,31) 23px 23px,rgb(193,29,31) 24px 24px,rgb(193,29,31) 25px 25px,rgb(193,29,31) 26px 26px,rgb(194,30,32) 27px 27px,rgb(194,30,32) 28px 28px,rgb(194,30,32) 29px 29px,rgb(194,30,32) 30px 30px,rgb(195,30,32) 31px 31px,rgb(195,30,32) 32px 32px,rgb(195,30,32) 33px 33px,rgb(195,30,32) 34px 34px,rgb(196,30,32) 35px 35px,rgb(196,30,32) 36px 36px,rgb(196,30,32) 37px 37px,rgb(196,30,32) 38px 38px,rgb(197,30,32) 39px 39px,rgb(197,30,32) 40px 40px,rgb(197,30,32) 41px 41px,rgb(198,30,32) 42px 42px,rgb(198,30,32) 43px 43px,rgb(198,30,32) 44px 44px,rgb(198,30,32) 45px 45px,rgb(199,30,32) 46px 46px,rgb(199,30,32) 47px 47px,rgb(199,30,32) 48px 48px,rgb(199,30,32) 49px 49px,rgb(200,30,32) 50px 50px,rgb(200,30,32) 51px 51px,rgb(200,30,32) 52px 52px,rgb(200,30,32) 53px 53px,rgb(201,31,33) 54px 54px,rgb(201,31,33) 55px 55px,rgb(201,31,33) 56px 56px,rgb(201,31,33) 57px 57px,rgb(202,31,33) 58px 58px,rgb(202,31,33) 59px 59px,rgb(202,31,33) 60px 60px,rgb(203,31,33) 61px 61px,rgb(203,31,33) 62px 62px,rgb(203,31,33) 63px 63px,rgb(203,31,33) 64px 64px,rgb(204,31,33) 65px 65px,rgb(204,31,33) 66px 66px,rgb(204,31,33) 67px 67px,rgb(204,31,33) 68px 68px,rgb(205,31,33) 69px 69px,rgb(205,31,33) 70px 70px,rgb(205,31,33) 71px 71px,rgb(205,31,33) 72px 72px,rgb(206,31,33) 73px 73px,rgb(206,31,33) 74px 74px,rgb(206,31,33) 75px 75px,rgb(206,31,33) 76px 76px,rgb(207,31,33) 77px 77px,rgb(207,31,33) 78px 78px,rgb(207,31,33) 79px 79px,rgb(208,32,34) 80px 80px}

  .azm-facebook { background: #4862a3; }

  .azm-google-plus { background: #dd4b39; }

  .azm-twitter { background: #55acee; }

  .azm-youtube { background: #d02022; }
  </style>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn azm-social azm-size-64 azm-circle azm-long-shadow azm-youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I removed two unnecessary divs. I set a valid link to CDN with Font Awesome. I did not make changes to CSS.

Note: If you add this rule to CSS: `.azm-long-shadow { overflow: hidden; }` you will get this:

[image: nicer output]

Comment: works but mine is not with the white icon color, it's black and the hover is white